# Make bootstrap dropdown behave like a select

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

So right now, my dropdown is nested inside some divs and tables and, when opened, it causes an overflow, which I can't seem to get it to go away. So I was wondering if there was a way for the dropdown to behave like a select box, in that it ignores all over flow and shows itself at the top regardless.

The main reason why I want to use dropdown is because select boxes (including ones by bootstrap) don't seem to have the ability to turn the textbox into an icon only (like how jQueryMobile can, though I do not wish to use jQueryMobile).

Here's a part of the code:

```
<table id="header_table" style="margin: 15px 0; overflow-y: visible;" class="header_background">
            <?php
            // Checkboxes
            if ($_mode == "inv")
            {
                echo "<td>"; 
                echo    "<div id='misc_header' class='resizable general header' style='min-width: 100px'>";
                echo        "<center>Misc</center>";
                echo    "</div>";
                echo "</td>";
            }

            foreach ( $_field_names[$_mode] as $key => $value ) 
            {
                echo "<td style='overflow-y: visible;'>";
                echo    "<div id='{$key}_header' class='resizable general header' style='min-width: 100px; overflow: visible;'>";
                echo        "<center>$value</center>";
                if (!preg_match("/dgclass|risk|msds|locations|hazard_codes/", $key))
                {
            ?>
                <div class="dropdown">
                  <button class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="dropdownMenu2" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-th-list"></span>
                  </button>
                  <ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenu2">
                    <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
                    <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
                  </ul>
                </div>          
                <select>
                    <option>hello</option>
                    <option>there</option>
                </select>

            <?php                   
                }
                echo    "</div>";
                echo "</td>";
            }

            //Actions
            if ($_mode == "inv")
            {
                echo "<td>";
                echo    "<div id='action_header' class='resizable general header' style='min-width: 100px'>";
                echo        "<center>Action</center>";
                echo    "</div>";
                echo "</td>";               
            }
            ?>
            <td id="scrollbar_td" style="display: none"></td>
        </table>
```

Comment: it would help if you posted all of your code. Edit your question and hit Ctrl + M and input your code

Comment: Your dropdown is inside a td?

Comment: @GermanoPlebani Yeah, which is also inside a resizable div.